# Spring Data JPA returning null repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When working with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA, I'm getting null repositories when `@Autowiring`.

I may have missed some piece of simple configuration, but after hours looking at it and reviewing the docs I find no flaws. I need antoher pair of eyes to take a fresh look.

Here is the relevant configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServerApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

A Service using the repository. When executing `doSomething()` the `repository` is null.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService{
  @Autowired
  private MyRepository repository;

  @Override
  public AnEntity doSomething(String index) {
    return repository.findOneByIndex(index);
  }
}
```

The Repository

```
public interface MyRepository extends   JpaRepository<AnEntity, String> {
  AnEntity findOneByIndex(String index);
}
```

The Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entities")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class AnEntity implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6256451671609986911L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String index;
  private String data;
}
```

The persistence.xml file

```xml
<persistence
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="default">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.myapp.AnEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.transactionType" value="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/authServer" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The POM

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.six2six</groupId>
        <artifactId>fixture-factory</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Think you miss the @Repository annotation

Comment: Post the entire class where you're using `MyService`.

Comment: Please add also your bean configuration - I'm not sure whether you are using Java config or XML or what...

Comment: @Betlista: Using Java Config. `@SpringBootApplication` is scanning all beans. The thing is that the Application does not fail to start as it should in case it was unable to find the Repository. Instead it works but does not inject the Repository into the Service.

Comment: @Jens:Regarding `@Repository` is no longer needed in latest Spring versions as shown in the docs.

Comment: What is index here. I don't see this field in AnEntity class

Comment: @chrylis: Your question pointed me into the right direction. Simple stupid error: The code was instantiating the Service explicitly, using `new`, instead of relying on Spring's CDI. Hence, the `@Autowire` in of the Repository in the Service was not being processed. Some times it's enough to discuss an error with someone :-). Thanks!

Comment: @Rohan: just corrected the question with your bug report and added the index field.

Comment: @dcerecedo: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @Rohan: Yes, solved! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I had an error in the code where the service was being instantiated explicitly, using `new`, instead of relying on Spring's CDI. Hence, the @Autowire in of the Repository in the Service was not being processed by Spring.

WRONG

```
//explicit instantiation. Spring not in charge so no repo injected
setService(new MyService());
```

RIGHT

```
//Spring CDI takes charge and autowires the Service and it's dependencies
@Autowired
private MyService myService;

public void someMethod(){
  setService(myService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyRepository class as follows:

```
public interface MyRepository extends   JpaRepository<AnEntity, Long> {
    public AnEntity findOneByData(String data);
    public AnEntity findOneByIndex(String index);
}
```

Comment: It is not really necessary to make explicit the base package to scan. The annotation by default starts at its package and scans upwards (towards the leaves) in the tree of packages. And if finding the Repository was the case, Spring throws an error indicating an unsatisfied dependency that could not wire. Which is not the case, as the application starts up.